# Herramienta externa para Visual Studio que genere error de compilación

Tags: visual-studio

Tengo una rutina programa en .NET la cual he añadido como "Herramienta externa" en Visual Studio (2013), la cual analiza cierta información de los archivos presentes en el directorio del proyecto que está siendo analizado (compilado).

También he logrado incluir la ejecución de dicha rutina de manera automática al compilar un proyecto.

Pero, ¿existe la posibilidad de que dicha rutina pueda generar de alguna manera información que Visual Studio la interprete como un problema "grave", y que se muestre como un error de compilación, o por último, como advertencia?.

Actualmente la rutina solo entrega su análisis en el apartado "Resultados", pero me gustaría que fuera un poco más restrictiva a la hora de preparar un ejecutable.

Comment: Tal vez podrias decir que tipo de informacion analiza. Podria ser un error que se pudiera agregar a los controles de errores comunes como una regla personalizada..

Comment: Hola @gbianchi! Es independiente la información que analiza, ya que esta es totalmente variada (analiza archivos .xml, .aspx.vb, etc)